# MongoDB(without Mongoos) and ElasticSearch Health Check in Nestjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, nestjs

I am new in Nestjs. and I want to add Health Check Route into my application.
I using Mongodb and ElasticSearch in my application. but I don't know to implement Health check for both.

I am not using Mongoose to connect to mongodb. I am directly using mongodb module. and in case of Elastic Search I am using @nestjs/elasticsearch module.

Comment: You would first need to define what you want the "Health Check" to actually do.

Comment: In Health Check I want to check service is Running or not

Answer (score 0):

For mongodb you can send ping command

```
 const res = await db.command({ ping: 1 })
 if (!res?.ok) {
   throw Error('Could not ping DB')
 }
```